# Altair Offline Rendering

Tags: python-3.x, altair

How can I create interactive charts that can be shared to others with limited internet connection?

My situation is such that I can generate and view the interactive charts I want, but due to VPN restrictions, my colleagues are not able to open the html charts that I generate. From the error message below, it seems like they are not able to render due to inability to connect to the web.

(error loading script https //cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega@5 noext)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interactive Altair/Vega-Lite charts require several javascript libraries to render the charts; in most cases these libraries are loaded from an external CDN, and so the chart will not be viewable without an internet connection.

You can get around this using the [altair_saver](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair_saver#usage) package, which is able to save HTML charts in "inline" mode, where the required javascript libraries are embedded directly in the chart output.

For example:

```
import altair_saver
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_point() #...

altair_saver.save(chart, 'chart.html', inline=True)
```

The resulting file can be viewed in a javascript-enabled web browser, and should work even without an internet connection.

Comment: thanks jake for sharing. I did just that and encountered "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2265' in position 247633: character maps to <undefined>" Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: If you can create a minimal example reproducing the error, please open a bug on the altair_saver repo and include it.

Comment: Thanks Jake. There is an existing example already raised in altair_saver repo:
https://github.com/altair-viz/altair_saver/issues/24